# I am trying to create THE TABLE ,ORA-00902: invalid datatype error..what's wrong here

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TYPE project_type AS OBJECT
(
  ID NUMBER,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(10),
  EMPLOYESS_NO VARCHAR(10),
  TYPE VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE project OF project_type
(
  CONSTRAINT unique_ex_ID
  UNIQUE(ID)
);
```

Comment: What you've shown works. Is the type actually being created? Where and how are you running these statements?

Comment: What tool are you using to execute this?

Answer (score -1):

Type is a reserved keyword, so I think it's barfing on TYPE VARCHAR. Change to EMPLOYEE_TYPE and see if that works

Comment: It's a keyword but not a reserved word, so it's legal here (though still better not to use it, of course).